# how to download package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu? example inside

Tags: package-management, downloads

I'm beginner for Unix. I can use "sudo apt-get install...." to install the package, but it is not the version I need(too new), that why I need to find and download an older version from other place.

I want to download the package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bowtie2/2.2.4-2. 
There are 3 files at the  bottom, which one should I download, how to install in ubuntu?

Thanks,

Comment: You could add that launchpad as ppa source to your apt-get sources list. Does that page list packages for your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: and by the way, what is your version

Comment: If you can't even tell those 3 files apart, are you really sure you want to download a source code archive for an unsupported Ubuntu release, modify it to work on your current release and then manually compile the package yourself? Besides, Ubuntu is *not* Unix!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `.deb` package of that version [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/bowtie2/2.2.4-2)

You can click the `.deb` file to download it or do this:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/190682664/bowtie2_2.2.4-2_amd64.deb
```

And then make sure you have the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6 libgcc1 libstdc++6
```

(probably all newest version already)

Then install:

```
sudo dpkg -i bowtie*
```

but this old version may not work well on your system and won't be updated...

Comment: Great, the deb file is what I want, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the page it says "Binary packages built by this source" and there you should click the "Bowtie2" link. On the page which follows is shows 3 versions to select from, so choose the 2.2.4-2 option.  The next page has, at the upper right corner of the window "Downloadable files" and there you want to click "bowtie2_2.2.4-2_amd64.deb" which will download the installable package.  Have Gdebi install it and there you go.